# Angular draggable/droppable table row

Tags: angular, draggable, droppable

I am using this plugin in Angular for event drag and drop in calendar, which is working fine:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-draggable-droppable

I use this same plugin on table for drag and drop to reorder rows. But, it is not giving effect like, if we move the row above/below table rows, then table row should be up and down on dragover.

```
<table mwlDroppable (drop)="arrange()">
<tr mwlDraggable><td>Name A</td><td>input field here</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name B</td><td>input field here</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name C</td><td>input field here</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link for Drag and drop in detail in table by using ng2-dnd refer this.

[angular 6 dnd](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/09/21/building-an-angular-4-drag-and-drop-application-in-15-minutes/)

Comment: cant I use the same plugin?

Comment: Did you try using GitHub of above plug in

Comment: https://github.com/akserg/ng2-webpack-demo. Check this github, Gave different type of dnd solutions.